# Is it possible to use both interrupts and ADC on the same pin of the RPi Pico?

Tags: gpio, pi-pico, interrupts

In order to use the Raspberry Pi Pico ADC on a pin, the `adc_gpio_init` function is used, which disables all digital functions (https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/pico-sdk/hardware.html#gab15d6e804715935b4e9b5027a2940910).

However, I'd like to both use the ADC (in free-running mode with DMA) and attach a falling-edge interrupt to the same pin. Is something like that possible, or do I have to connect the same signal to two pins?

Answer (score 1):

My solution ended up being:

```c
gpio_init(26 + CAPTURE_CHANNEL);
gpio_disable_pulls(26 + CAPTURE_CHANNEL);
gpio_set_irq_enabled_with_callback(26 + CAPTURE_CHANNEL, GPIO_IRQ_EDGE_FALL, true, gpio_callback);
```

This seems to configure the pin as an input without pull-up / pull-down resistors, and leaves both ADC and digital functions enabled.

Any amendments to the answer are welcome.